# Drawing in color in Rebol/Red

Tags: draw, rebol

In the following code from: http://business-programming.com/business_programming.html , I want to add a button to convert line being drawn in blue rather than in white color. I have tried to add `color: blue` at various places but it is not working:

[image: drawing]

```
view center-face layout [
      ; color: blue                                     ; does not work.
    s: area black 650x350 feel [
        engage: func [f a e] [
              ; color: blue                             ; does not work here also.
            if a = 'over [
                append s/effect/draw e/offset
                show s
            ]
            if a = 'up [append s/effect/draw 'line] ; tried adding "'pen 'blue" here before 'line
        ]
    ] effect [draw [line]]
    b: btn "Save" [
        save/png %a.png to-image s 
        alert "Saved 'a.png'"
    ]
    btn "Clear" [
        s/effect/draw: copy [line]
        show s]
    ]
```

How can I make the line to draw in blue rather than white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify

```
] effect [draw [line]]
```

to

```
] effect [draw [pen blue line]]
```

see [REBOL 2: View Draw Dialect](http://www.rebol.com/docs/draw.html)